# play media in the background

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have created a very simple app with one page which contains a listview and a mediaplayerelement. The list displays some radio streams URLs, at the tap on the list the URL is sent to the mediaplayerelement and the station starts playing.

I have added the background media playback capability to my project and the music continue playing when the App goes to the background but stops when the device screen is switched off, what do I have to do to have the music continue playing even when the screen is off.
I have used this link as a reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/background-audio.
Thanks 
H

code sample

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var builder = new StationBuilder();
        var jsonSource = await builder.getStations();
        var list = builder.getResults(jsonSource);

        stationList.ItemsSource = list;
    }


    private void Button_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var o = 0;
        var url = (sender as AppBarButton).Tag.ToString();
        player.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(url));
    }
```

Comment: I tested the official sample:[BackgroundMediaPlayback](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundMediaPlayback). The music is still on when the screen is off. So maybe post some codes or share a sample to show what you are trying.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. this is my code:

Comment: I have added my code, as I said before it's a very simple App I didn't use the whole code from the sample, have U done this before? what's the minimum that I have to implement?

Comment: Could you please post the codes of `StationBuilder`?